# Friendlier text for the edit page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits

Discussed in [this meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127538/181928) was a suggested rewording to the edit page to make it less scary for new users. The current wording of "You do not have edit privileges." may put new users off, as (IMO) it sounds too much like "You cannot do this!"

A friendlier alternative settled upon was "Your edit will be reviewed by the community", possibly with a link to a page explaining the review process, including things like attribution and the reputation benefits.

This ticket mainly here as a reminder, at waffles request. :)

Comment: I think the idea was supposed to be: "You do not have *full* edit privileges *yet*, so..."

Comment: Since no changes have been made yet I'm sure there's time to suggest different wording. Personally I feel positive language is more likely to encourage new users - "You don't have X" suggests a barrier to entry, whereas the wording above suggests that anyone's contributions will be given some degree of attention. That's just my two cents though. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just nuked the start of the sentence ... instead, it will now say:

```
 <p>Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.</p>
 <p>We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary.</p>
```