# Regain of reputation from downvoted and deleted answers - update FAQ

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, deleted-answers, help-center

I have down voted and flagged two answers as "not an answer." Doing so reduced my reputation by 2 (1 for each down vote). It seemed both of my flags were helpful and both answers were deleted.

As requested, flag screenshot:

[image]

As far as I can remember, when a down voted answer got deleted, we got our reputation back.

So I did by manually [re-calculating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6770/why-dont-i-reclaim-my-downvote-penalty-when-the-post-i-downvoted-is-deleted/6772#6772). You do not have to re-calculate yourself as it will automatically happen at some point.

Rep regain screenshot:

[image]

This information is either very hard to find in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) or [SO Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) or [Meta Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)... or it *doesn't exist.* It only mentions that you lose 1 rep point for down voting answers, but it doesn't say that you **get it back if the answer is deleted**. It's commonly known by more experienced users but think about new users, or the ones who are not aware of it...

Let everyone know that voting **bad** answers is a **good** thing! That temporary loss of 1 rep point *will be given back to you* in case the *answer is deleted*.

Based on the above, I think the FAQ and Help Center should be updated.

Comment: IMO, I think it would help keep SO standards high with just a bit more effort from the community. Simply make people aware that downvoting **bad** answers is a good thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030700/reduce-string-and-keep-zeroes-intact/19031323#19031323 - (-1) but with 30+ views nobody else cared :/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Yes please**. This will encourage users (probably new on Stack Exchange) to downvote VLQ/SPAM/incorrect answers without *rep-lose-phobia*. We can simply add this information in *You gain reputation when* section somewhat like this:

- A non-wiki answer you have downvoted is removed: +1

Comment: Maybe we could even raise it to +2 to reward good flagging behavior, but that might be abused

Comment: @Doorknob - Your concern is correct.

Comment: wonder if it would be accurate to describe this using words "You _gain_ reputation"? Reputation is rather "restored", does word "gain" fits here?

Comment: @gnat - Not sure if it is *gain* but our [current Meta FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/187824) stats *you remove a downvote from an answer: +1* under *gain*.

Comment: @hims056 all right, as long as there's already a precedent, I'm fine with that

Comment: @hims056, Wait, to be clear, do you mean *both* the voter (1 rep) and the votee (2 rep) will get their rep back, or do you mean only the voter will get the rep back while the votee continues to have -2?

Answer (score 4):

I see a lot of value in this idea because any idea to encourage downvoting of really poor quality answers is a good one.

However, I am concerned that it will lead to a increase in flagging posts<sup>1</sup> that you downvote just to get the rep back.  Or whining if/when the flag is declined such as:

> "I downvoted this post and flagged it, but a mod declined my flag.  And when I try to undo my downvote to get my rep back, I get an error message that says my vote is locked.  How can I get my rep back?"

<sup>1</sup> - Specifically I am referring to improper flagging of posts, such as flags for incorrect posts (which shouldn't be flagged) or other similar issues.

Comment: Why do you always say about [Sungliyakam](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197495/187824 "10K+ on Meta only")? :)

Comment: @hims056 because I happen to like [Chinese food in Toronto](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yelp.com%2Fbiz%2Fsuvaiyakam-restaurant-scarborough-2&ei=X-g6Uq_BNpKl4AOKh4GIAw&usg=AFQjCNHtCpFDi22OfB4YdfXVr0-KZNHNUw&sig2=eAWe8Inrtcgt5rmQH21QGw&bvm=bv.52288139,d.dmg) (ok not spelled the same, but pretty close)

Comment: Which is why, with my low rep, I only downvote answers I'm sure will be deleted.

Comment: @psubsee2003, Uh, I don't think people will bother doing that to get back **1** rep.....