# Is there a way to turn off this disturbing green light from the status bar?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, top-bar

Unlike notifications for the incoming messages, this number is absolutely POINTLESS. It requires no actual action to perform, yet it jumps in the eye with the same force. I don't like no pointless interface elements, Thank you.

Besides that, what I am supposed to do by noticing it? To race and see which of my answers were rewarded? To cherish *such* a vanity? Or what?

Update.
These two paragraphs above can be considered as two separate feature requests. I am not as far as proposing a second one (though I'd be happy if this number were turned off for all, as it does more harm than good - but it seems the mission impossible). What I am asking is a setting to turn it off.

Comment: It show the reputation changes, that's not pointless. Unless reputation is pointless?

Comment: Fully agreed. People were already obsessing over their imaginary unicorn points, the notification can only make things worse.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Not entirely pointless, but not significant enough (imho) to have every +5 or +10 displayed so prominently (and after a while, annoyingly).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It makes reputation seem more important than we would like it to be

Comment: Such gamification extras provoke users to use stackoverflow little more (my opinion). Some bonus and reward for the users maybe stimulates them to be more active in the comments and answers. If this helps this project being so active, strict, reasonable and useful for a huge societies, maybe no-so-proved UI elements as we think, make great sense. I think we can live with it. We have this large resource with real specialists from all over the world for free, instant and guaranteed with the votes. Wow, right?

Comment: @AntonRadev we don't need to promote answers. We need to promote community moderation.

Comment: I avoid clicking on it so that it stays.  And I seem to have gotten used to it.

Comment: We had all that before the new top bar @AntonRadev.

Comment: @AntonRadev yes, no doubt reputation points provoke the answers quantity. The problem is answers *quality*. Dunno for other tags, but PHP section is FLOODED with answers written without any knowledge or even without *reading the question at all*. While I believe that a *good* answer can be written only out of a desire to share knowledge (which already a great stimulant) and never out of desire to see more green numbers.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a way to make it fade away after popping up and the user seeing it. Then at least it wouldn't *remain* an eyesore (even if it would still appear as one originally).

Comment: @Yannis people used to hover their display name in the old top bar to see the reputation changes. See other requests here to bring it back. With the new design, no need to hover like crazy anymore, it's always there visible and live. And those are many people as far as I can tell. Still not significant enough? :)

Comment: So? "People want this" is never a good reason to build a feature @ShaWizDowArd (see countless requests for poll questions). Also, people hovering like crazy is a sign of obsession. Certainly significant, but not something I'd want to encourage.

Comment: @Yannis so you can also take badges away, using this same logic. Bottom line, the team had their reason to put this feature in place same way they had reason to put the reputation changes hover-box before. Nobody really asked for it, and it's OK to have two different opinions. :)

Comment: I tried the corresponding dropdown menu on day one and haven't opened it since. I find the indicator bothersome only when the number of digits increases, which fortunately happens at a logarithmically decreasing rate. I'm holding out for a bug report when it reaches 5 figures if it encroaches on the inbox space.

Comment: Does this have to be a *yes* or *no* discussion? It could be added to the user preferences.

Comment: @Gilles workaround of refusing to use a feature reminds me of recent [CV reviews strike](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208220/165773). I guess I will give it a try, the only inconvenience is that occasional mis-click on that menu will drag one back to the beginning of that _logarithmically decreasing rate_

Comment: See [Gallery of custom styles and/or scripts for the top-bar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210041/gallery-of-custom-styles-and-or-scripts-for-the-top-bar) for ways to change the appearance of the top bar.

Comment: @gnat I don't refuse to use that feature. I don't use it because I don't find it useful (and indeed I see this benefit in never using it).

Comment: It's not that annoying, but being told I have +100 points every time I join a new StackExchange site is a little misleading, if we could turn that off it would help.

Comment: Reputation is indeed pointless. I thought there was consensus on that.

Comment: +1 just to add a bit of green on your screen!

Comment: "*Reputation is indeed pointless. I thought there was consensus on that.*" - @Pëkka Saywhatnow? What about the [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), and all the rhetoric from [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)? I would say rep is a big part of what keeps new users coming back (though it's probably less of a factor for veterans / people with more than 20k rep).

Comment: @jadarnel27 how dare you contradict a man with a Heavy Metal Umlaut? Seriously though - yeah, you're right of course. But reputation as a "ohh look, I got +10 again!" is meaningless, and skewing the system to put *even more* emphasis on that aspect is the wrong way to go.

Comment: @Pëkka That umlaut *is* pretty rock 'n roll.  I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: @jadarnel27 that's the spirit. I'll let you off with a warning this time.

Comment: @jadarnel27 reputation-based privileges is the same humburg as well. A diligent good-for-nothing can earn himself whatever privilege by just answering dozens stupid questions a day. WITHOUT any friggin knowledge. The only ability for copy/paste is needed. And no matter if his answers are right or wrong - he will be getting his rotten rep. Because beside this rep gamble there should be a **quality check**, but there is none.

Comment: It would be a good feature for addicts like me, if it would show *today's rep gain*. So I would see "hey, you hit your rep cap, take it easy. get some stuff done. go for a walk. take a bath". But when I click it (and I *have to* - it's flashing and saying "click me, plz!"), it gets reset and thus serves no purpose further.

Answer (score 31):

For a [serial answers downvoter](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5413/31260) like me, this friggin' light turns on every time next piece of garbage is [removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197507/165773) from the site (happens quite frequently).

I am of course glad that site gets rid of low quality content, but not to extent to celebrate it with **obtrusive green fireworks** every minute or so. Especially since numbers that pop up don't even come close to [how much rep I gained since the last time I checked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208058/165773)...

> [image: tbd]

Comment: Loving your artistic work.

Comment: @Coulton real artistry is when top bar turns boring stuff like `-1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1` into bright green **+21**. [A Kind Of Magic](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWf5BLUOhNM)

Comment: @gnat: [You are refering to a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208575/new-rep-indicator-keeps-popping-up)

Comment: @juergend even if the numbers were reasonable, it would not change my desire to turn these "obtrusive green fireworks" off. Changes these celebrate simply aren't worth breaking my attention

Comment: +1 for "green fireworks"

Answer (score 7):

## Yes

I made a couple of [userscripts](https://stackapps.com/q/4429/4644) that either hide the green notifications entirely, or alternatively just hides the numbers (the rep icon still turns green but it's much less intrusive).

Answer (score 3):

While I wish every feature change could make everybody happy, I'm pretty convinced that this specific change is a net plus for the vast majority of our users.

The strategy of many other sites is to offer multiple panels of preference checkboxes so that users can customize things like this. Not only are we philosophically opposed to that approach, it also makes things like caching very difficult for a high-traffic site like ours.

Comment: No, not a net plus for many users. I (and others) don't care about every stupid rep change. This only supports rep-hunters, which is wrong.

Comment: It's not just a nuisance for anybody who is a bit more active on the sites - like it was said in the comments above, showing rep changes this obnoxiously puts even *more* emphasis on the gaming/rep-hunting aspect of the site. Is that really the message we want to send?

Comment: I assume it's fairly effective in engaging new users, @Pëkka. It drives me up a wall too, but unless we all ragequit in annoyance I suspect from the Stack Exchange side of the fence it's a net win.

Comment: Or just ignore it. I haven't clicked on mine in weeks and it's become this static icon that sits on that bar. Doesn't bother me.

Comment: The only problem with high traffic is a technology used. PHP-based sites offer good usability telling no such cheap excuses.

Comment: @Mysticial I kinda love the attitude. Especially after all the buzzwords telling how important YOU for the site and stuff. YOU are indeed important as long as you make this site run for free. But you are nobody when asks a site to do anything for you.

Comment: @Mysticial it could be actually useful if it would light up for downvotes, which you usually want to check out. But it doesn't. I just tested. *Shaking head*

Comment: The caching argument is completely bogus since this particular widget is by definition different for every user.