# Achievements can be used against us by trolls

Tags: discussion, top-bar, trolling, achievements-dialog

See this:

> [image]

It's real. (Thanks [Manishearth](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/178438/manishearth) for helping me on this!)

Any user with upvote privilege can simply click the upvote button repeatedly to cause this to any other user, at any time.

How can we block this? I couldn't come with a concrete suggestion so your ideas are welcome.

Comment: Tha works if there is no tracking of who voted for whom. So the question is, when repeatedly clicking, would this be recorded for each click? Probably not. But can moderators see who voted on whom? If so you can at least identify the account.

Comment: @Devolus no, mods can't know but it's not relevant and that's not what I'm asking. I want the achievements mechanism that is responsible to show that green number, to somehow identify such thing and prevent it.

Comment: Hey, that's the private message feature people have been asking for! All you need is to know morse code.

Comment: @Mat that's plain stroke of genius!

Comment: They could just implement some kind of cooldown period for too many votes cast or undone within a couple of seconds. Chances are those aren't benign votes anyway.

Comment: @slhck isn't there already? ... oh, there isn't.

Comment: @JanDvorak there is only for the reputation display in user profile reputation tab - otherwise it will show +10/-10/+10/-10 events like crazy. :)

Comment: @Mat except your timing must be fast enough to fit into 5 minutes vote lockdown period, yet small enough to be readable after a network jitter is applied.

Comment: @Jan 2K troll can always make a minor edit and keep spamming the upvote arrow forever. :-D

Comment: @ShadowWizard but then these PMs are no longer anonymous

Comment: They are not even private, actually. Just volatile.

Comment: On a side note, why does the tavern chat new message indicator flicker as well?

Comment: @JanDvorak that's because I was chatting with Manish and telling him what to do in order to reproduce this. No worry it's not part of the reported abuse. :)

Comment: Ohmygod, it's... it's [Oscillating](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/166483#166483)!

Comment: Yes yes, it's working I know you don't have to test it on me! :D

Comment: You are wearing the hat!! Did you perform this exercise while Winterbash; or have you got yourself a special feature to use the hats throughout the year?? I guess the second option is the right one... BTW, I hope you enjoyed the trolling that I did for the last minute or so :-)

Comment: @Aditya so it was you! lol! As for hat, it was recorded few days ago when Winter Bash was still active (and it's not me by the way, I can't give myself reputation) and I was just slow to bake this discussion.

Comment: I find the new `+REP` pop-ups irritating already anyway ;0 (the new bar is OK otherwise).

Comment: @BartoszKP [others too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210118/152859) but it was declined... personally I do find it nice feature.

Comment: ... Quick! Make this an IPhone app! if [Curiosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiosity_%E2%80%93_What's_Inside_the_Cube%3F) managed to sell what it did, you could be sitting on a pile of money before ye knew. You just need to add some stats showing how many clicks you did.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist that's an excellent idea!

Comment: @ShadowWizard. Just remember my name in the special thanks section ^_^

Comment: There is a rate limit per-post, but it hardly does anything…

Comment: Is this an actual problem encountered somewhere by someone?

Comment: @SQB it is irritating, so yeah, can be considered a problem.

Comment: But has it actually been exploited/observed in the wild @ShadowWizard?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker good question, I *think* what sparked this was such a case, but "only" something like 5 blinks, so I thought "hey, this can be much worse..."

Comment: Given that virtually nobody has been a "victim" of this horrific exploit, and that there are exactly no consequences (unless [an epileptic doctor is using SE while investigating extraterrestrial bacteria in an underground laboratory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Andromeda_Strain)), I'm pretty sure it's a non-issue.

Comment: @Jason one of those "no issue until it becomes an issue" things. I just saw a possible exploit and decided to try and discuss it, I'm pretty sure that rate limit of 30 vote/unvote wasn't there when I reported it.

Comment: What are the consequences of somebody doing this?

Comment: @JasonC becoming irritated, distracted, etc.

Answer (score 15):

According to [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide), after you have undone and redone your vote 30 times, it is locked in:

[image]

So you would only be able to do this 30 times for each post.

Comment: At which point you could move on to the next post? :-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker - and then you'll get in trouble for serial voting :P

Comment: Not if you cycle the votes only 28 times, before it gets locked, and make sure you don't leave a vote.

Comment: That would be a *very* dedicated troll.  Oh, err, unless it can be scripted -- that would be bad.

Comment: @MonicaCellio everything can be scripted. Its always only the question how much time someone is willing to invest in the script.

Answer (score 2):

I might suggest implementing a similar limit seen with undoing and redoing upvotes with accepting answers.

[The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) says the following about accepting answers:

- All must wait 15 minutes after asking to accept any answer
- All must wait 48 hours after asking to accept *own* answer

This says nothing about flicking the acceptance on and off like the asker is talking about for upvotes. I think a similar limit needs to be implemented for accepting answers to prevent abuse like this.

Even with the 30 undo and redo limit for votes, this still allows *some* abuse like this, since it's pretty easy to count off 25 or so undo/redos and not hit the 30 limit. If you had to wait 15 seconds or so to undo or redo a vote or accepted answer, it would completely prevent this sort of rapid-fire on-and-off abuse of the system.