# Gaming system with accepts

Tags: bug, status-declined, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

Well, it is not really efficient, but gives some reps (tried two days ago, only 41 reps :-) ).

I have, **for example**, 50 question where I had accepted answers. And 101 reps, because each accept gives you 2 reps.
Then I offer 100 rep bounty (or lose this rep by some other way, e.g. downvotes), unaccept and accept answers again. I am again at 101 reps. Yoyo!

Comment: Is *that* why you have been spamming my reputation tab with unaccepts and accepts?

Comment: But... downvote faster! I didn't expect such... tiny reaction!

Comment: Your post isn't really clear. Can you provide more evidence, like screenshots?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wait. Screenshots? Why?.. What for?

Comment: @nicael because when you unaccept it cause -15 rep change to the answer author and when you accept again it's +15. The user then see this and get irritated.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I know

Comment: @ShadowWizard - to the answerer. Here he's talking about the -2/+2 to the asker.

Comment: Anyway congrats, you've just [used my idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215234/achievements-can-be-used-against-us-by-trolls)!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234279/about-rep-changes-and-gaming-system-using-them#comment770606_234347

Comment: You... don't give up, do you?

Comment: Have you considered using the system as it was intended instead of spamming people's inboxes? It would be a much more practical and beneficial use of your time.

Comment: RE: Your edit. You'll possibly achieve your aim there, but you might get more than you are bargaining for. Reporting something is one thing, but once you do...

Comment: @Andrew'saUnitato But yep, I reported, and... what... yep. What do I do?

Comment: Once you've tested (arguably way too much) and reported, you *stop*.

Comment: @Andrew'saUnitato I stopped. :/ Why do you think I continue to do this?

Comment: "I stopped..." ... "...I continue..."; yeah.

Comment: @Andrew'saUnitato What? I told that I'll find a new [hole](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234279/about-rep-changes-and-gaming-system-using-them#comment770460_234347), I found.

Comment: @Martijn you are not allowed to remove mod-only tags :D

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Let's review a few things involved here:

- A historical patch of reputation that wasn't real-time, when synced meaning bounty offers that would have required going negative.
- A desire for a reputation timeline that never dips below 1.
- A mechanism that adjusts reputation with an award amounting to the reputation not actually chronologically present when the bounty was invoked (1 second before the bounty, to be precise).
- A rep recalc system triggered on major events that does the adjustments.
- A clear history of every one of these adjustments which are incredibly rare today.
- An exploit of the system that necessitates you **always sitting at less than 101 reputation**.

So yes, as it sits the only way to exploit this loophole is to gain and lose rep, spam people's profiles, trigger the award system that leaves a *very* clear trail of what you're doing and we can alert on.  And you're doing all of this to sit in a privilege range where you can't even comment.

I have 2 options here:

1. Remove the inherent ability to do this, sacrificing API and timeline stability to do so (since it's just an artifact of how we choose for the system to work)
2. Ban the user doing it

If you're curious, I can tell you which is more likely to happen.

Comment: I'm gonna play obtuse here ;)

Comment: @nicael you'd surely have found some other hobby in the meantime :D

Comment: _If you're curious, I can tell you which is more likely to happen._ Nailed it . Haha