# Upvotes that make the post’s daily reputation total zero seem to come from nowhere

Tags: bug, reputation, achievements-dialog

Today, the following happened to me:

- I posted a question.
- I received five downvotes and one upvote on that question.
- I clicked on the achievements dropdown, seeing a −5 from that question.
- I received another upvote on that question (I checked).
- The achievements alert got activated again, showing me a +5. However, when I clicked on it, the question that was the source of all of this was not shown:

  [image: screenshot of achievements dropdown]

  (Just in case this matters, the question in question was on Meta, but it was not the one about mobile pages shown in the above screenshot.)

So, it seems that posts whose daily reputation total is zero are not shown in the achievements dropdown, even when they yielded a recent reputation gain.  This is sub-optimal and confusing.

Comment: Well, suppose they would show, will it have "+0" next to it?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this is a bug. The achievements dialog is showing reputation **changes**. If there is no change in a certain post, that post should not appear there, and the count is made on daily basis.

Consider the more common case of accepting an answer, then unaccepting it in the same day. With the current system, you won't have an item in the dialog, as expected. No need to show something that was undone.

That said, in case of a "tie" between upvotes/downvotes reputation, I would like to have it be split into two items: one showing the reputation gain from upvotes, and another item showing the reputation loss from downvotes.

Comment: *Consider the more common case of accepting an answer, then unaccepting it in the same day. With the current system, you won't have an item in the dialog, as expected. No need to show something that was undone.* – On the other hand, if somebody unaccepts your answer, you see this, and then your answer is accepted again, you probably also would have a +15 popup coming from seemingly  nowhere.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft you mean something like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215234/achievements-can-be-used-against-us-by-trolls)?

Comment: No. That’s about the popup, not what’s beneath.