# Combine rep for accepting answer with question's rep

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, achievements-dialog

When I accept an answer for my question I get +2 rep for that. Is it possible to combine reputation points for question with +2 for accepting answer for the same question in the achievements dialog? Now I see them separated:

> [image: q+a]

Comment: They are given for different tasks. Votes, edits, and accepted answers are different tasks and **will be split up intentionally**, so you don't think you got 4 upvotes and 1 downvote for 17 rep when in reality it's just 3 upvotes. Also, nice hand-drawn red circle.

Comment: @devRicher 4 upvotes and 1 downvotes will give 20-2 = 18 rep (not 17). Even if tasks are different they could be combined in the achievements dialog. According your thoughts upvotes and downvotes also should be separated to distinguish total 0 score (-10 = downvotes, +10 = upvotes) from no votes at all like in [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287199/339911). Thanks for praising circles:)